# Getting TermSet and Terms from Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Field

Tags: client-object-model, 2013, taxonomy, term-store, term

I'm having a hard time trying fo figure this one out. 
I can only use Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client for this. I'am working with Sharepoint 2013.

I need to list all Fields (Metadata) For a certain content type that are actually Manage Metadata TermSet fields. I can already get the ContentType and access its Fields. Once there I can find all the TermSet Fields base on Field.TypeAsString just like this :

```
if (field.TypeAsString == "TaxonomyFieldType" || field.TypeAsString == "TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti")
```

So What I'm wondering now is How could I get the proper TermStore in order to get the TermSet ? I know I need the TermStore Id, but I didn't find it anywhere in the Field's properties. I'm currently looking at MSDN but didn't find anything yet.

Thanks for any information you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will give you what you are looking for...

```
// get the TaxonomyField from the Site Columns in the sitecollectionTaxonomyField 
field = (TaxonomyField)site.RootWeb.Fields[TAXONOMYFIELDID]; 
// get the Term Store ID from the field
Guid termStoreId = field.SspId; 
// Open a taxonomysession and get the correct termstoreTaxonomy
Session session = new TaxonomySession(site);
TermStore termStore = session.TermStores[termStoreId];
```

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did point me in the right direction!

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field does not have any "SspId" property BUT I finally found it in the "SchemaXml" property along with the TermSetId.

With those I can now get the "TermStore -> TermSet -> Term -> Label" structure I need.

Just a bit of code to do and I think I should be good!

Thanks again

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it figured out!